# different javascript behavior in joomla->sourcerer

Tags: javascript, joomla

The folowing code inserted into joomla->customHTML module is not working however it works in ordinary LAMP.

```
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "\"Lorem\" ipsum\
\"dolor\"\
\"sit amet\"\
";
```

Inserted by sourcerer system plug in.

Not suprisingly this works for both

```
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "\"Lorem\" ipsum\"dolor\"\"sit amet\"";
```

Is there way to make this environment more stable?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't allow multi-line strings, it's not php.

Also Joomla custom HTML module will usually strip `<script>` code

Besides custom HTML, there is an extension by nonumber.nl that allows you to insert javascripts easily in the page, the name is sourcerer if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I am using sourcerer as i mentioned.

Comment: Using backslash clears the multi-line errors for other environments.

Answer (score 0):

Creating local files on server and adding them to the page cleared all errors caused by collisions with joomla.

I am now also able to work with editors that i used to.

I simply created a .js .php .css files on server and add them with sourcerer plug-in to the page under joomla.

```
{source} //source tag for joomla sourcerer plug-in
  <link href="/includes/comsettings/comstyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<?php
  require './includes/comsettings/comsettings.php';
  echo '<script src="./includes/comsettings/comsettings.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
?>
{/source}
```

This way, all operations done by joomla editors to the source are overridden. Except, of course variables created by joomla for frame work (Example $_POST array is ,still, already set on all pages)

Every arcticle or customHTML module (created by joomla beckend) are created under public root directory that you installed joomla in. While inserting your files (custom ,non-joomla originated) to the page, you can navigate from root to any directory (readable/executable dirs) which your files created under it.